# Wi-Fi connects but can't browse

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, wi-fi

I'm opening a virtual router through my laptop, and my Galaxy S2 can see and connect to it fine. However, when I try to do anything that requires the network, it doesn't work (for example, I can't browse). The top bar shows the wireless icon and the connection appears perfect. What is causing this?

Comment: What operating system is your laptop running and how are you setting up the connection on the laptop?

Comment: windows7, i'm creating hot spot trough mhotspot, and it's working how i sad but why can't do any stuff in the phone when it seys that i'm connected

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "do anything that is connected to a network"? Like access //mycomputername?

Connecting to a share on a computer connected to the same network is not part of wifi, it is another protocol called [SMB or CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block). Android does not support connecting to cifs out of the box. There are apps that allow you to browse for files on network shares, like [Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) (with the [SMB plugin](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro.smb)).

There are Custom ROMs that do have built in support for CIFS, like CyanogenMod for example.

Comment: But i don't need to share files, i need to share network connection.

Comment: so you want to share your internet connection from your phone with your computer?

Comment: No.. from the computer to the phone

Comment: the computer doesn't share its network connection when you have a router. but I don't really think I understand your question then. If you are connected to the wireless router then you should have internet access on your device.

Comment: Man, I have virtual router, it's not a device, just a router. Doesn't mater i'll try something about the DNS and IP becouse, i think this is the problem, and will produce results, soon.